# Installing Chinese Language Pack on Linux Red Hat 6.0 Enterprise

Tags: linux, redhat

I have a Linux Red Hat 6.0 Enterprise server in China and need to install the Chinese language pack on it.  It's current language is English, and I have a progress database that outputs some characters in Chinese, but doesn't render right since I don't have the Chinese language/fonts installed.  How can I get these installed?  I don't have the installation CD, as I inherited this server from my predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see all language packages available through this interface, you can type the following command:

```
# yum grouplist
```

This will output all group packages, the last section of which is “Available Language Groups”. Note that some packs may already be installed, in which case, they will be visible under “Installed Language Packs” at the top of the list. In this case, “chinese-fonts” is now “Chinese Support”.

To install chinese package, run the following command:

```
# yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"
```

Comment: Here is what I get when I try that:    [root@pvgqadsvr2 etc]# yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Error: No group data available for configured repositories
[root@pvgqadsvr2 etc]# yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Warning: Group Chinese Support does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
[root@pvgqadsvr2 etc]#

Comment: [root@pvgqadsvr2 etc]# yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Error: No group data available for configured repositories
[root@pvgqadsvr2 etc]# yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Setting up Group Process
Warning: Group Chinese Support does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
[root@pvgqadsvr2 etc]#